# Email Template Issues - WP-Invoice - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have designed an email template for my WP-Invoices.

I have designed the template as so:

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color:#efefef;">
    <div style="width:80%; margin-left:10%; background-color:white; padding:25px;">   
        <p>Dear %recipient%,<p> 
        <div style="width:80%; margin-left:10%; background-color:#eaeaea; text-align:center; padding:50px 0">
            <p>%business_name% has sent you the %type% for:</p> 
            <p style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px;">%amount%</p> 
            <p style="padding-bottom:15px">You may pay, view and print the invoice PDF online by visiting the following link:<p>
            <div style="width:30%; padding:0 35%">
                <button style="background:#018fcf; border:0; border-radius:35px; padding:15px 70px; margin:auto;"><a style="color:white; font-size:20px; href="%link%">View invoice</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px;">          
            <p>%description%</p> 
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px;">
            <p>For questions about this invoice, please contact</p>
                  <a href="mailto:accounts@email.co.uk">mailto:accounts@email.co.uk</a>
        <div>
            <p>Best regards,</p>
            <p>%business_name%</p> 
            <p>%business_email%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, I am needing to edit the email before sending.

The styles get negated because the plugin seems to insert '\' at the start and end:

```
<div style="\....\">....</div>

<div style=\"width:80%; margin-left:10%; background-color:white; padding:25px;\">....</div>
```

Does anyone know how to prevent the plugin or Wordpress from adding the slashes?

Comment: what is the exact plugin? please provide a link

Comment: @andrew the plugin is wp-invoice - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-invoice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will work. I had a look at the plugin's code and it looks like the email is sent out in `class.ajax.php` line 196 `static function send_notification`

Try adding the following to your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('wpi_notification_message', 'remove_slashes');
function remove_slashes($message){
        return stripslashes($message);
}
```

It should be noted though, that if it works, it will remove **all** backslashes from the message body

Comment: I have tried adding that code to functions.php and also creating a plugin override but neither seem to work :-(

Comment: Plugin override:

<?php

/**
 *  Plugin Name: Override WP-Invoice
 *  Description: Custom override to add class to element
 *  Version: 1.0.0
 *  Author: Me
 */

add_filter('wpi_notification_message', 'remove_slashes');
function remove_slashes($message){
        return stripslashes($message);
}

Comment: your solution worked... I had to change the top line in add_filter, notification should have been message.
I changed it to

    'add_filter('wpi_notification_content', 'remove_slashes');'

works great, thanks a lot

Comment: Ok! glad you got it sorted, I didn't actually install the plugin I just looked though through the code. looks like I got the wrong filter sorry about that

Comment: Was easy sorted, you done the hard part :-). Much appreciated